# Draw-overs still appear while app is in Pin Mode

Tags: android, android-screen-pinning

I am making an educational app and I take advantage of pin mode to lock the users in my app but the draw-overs still appear on top of the app even when the app is in pin mode. Apps like Facebook Messenger can draw over the app while the app is in pin mode. Is there a way to restrict the draw overs entirely while in pin mode?

Comment: Related: [How to detect when Facebook messenger bubble is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27632995/295004)